# Illegal Knight vs Number 59 Crooked Cook

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I just want to know this because I don't think it works.
The effect of Illegal Knight has you target up to 2 cards your opponent controls and summon it to their field and if you did bounce it back to their hand, so if I have Number 59 Crooked Cook on the field would the effect of Illegal Knight to summon on my field and then bounce it back work. I know it will still summon to my field but will it stil bounce my card?

Answer (score 1):

The ability of **Number 59 Crooked Cook** has the requirement that it's controller has no other cards on the field, which means that **Illegal Knight** transferring control deactivates it's protection from other cards' effects.

When resolving effects with multiple steps you re-evaluate the board at each point which means **Illegal Knight** will return **Number 59 Crooked Cook** to your hand.

Unfortunately because this happens in the middle of resolving **Illegal Knight**'s ability you cannot activate **Number 59 Crooked Cook**'s *(Quick Effect)* to destroy **Illegal Knight**.